# Can my hemlock trees be saved?

Tags: diagnosis, evergreens, dead-branch

I am not entirely sure they are hemlock trees. 
They were not doing so hot when I moved in 2015, but I think it's getting worse over the past few years. They are located near Albany, New York State, US.

Photos are taken last Sunday, Jun 3rd, 2018. There are growths on all green branches, but the dead branches are looking so dead, and there are branches turning red. The tree might be around 20 years old.
Could someone tell the problem based on the photos? Can they be saved?

[image]

[image]

[image]
There is still new growth

[image]

Comment: could we have a close-up picture of the bark high-up where the most branches are dead? Just to see if there are holes or anything.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to circling roots, borers, Wooly Aphid...hard to say without actually seeing the tree first hand.  If you look at the limbs and see little white nodules on the bark...it's probably Wooly Aphids.  They've been a huge problem in your area.
The taller tree cannot be saved.  Depending upon the cause, the shorter might be savable..but doubtful.